# How can I create a new Sitecore Marketplace module

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

I was wondering how should I go about creating a Sitecore module. I did take a look at [How can I develop module in Sitecore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30701785) and found some information there. However, I am still not clear on few things like:

1. I am assuming I would use Sitecore Instance Manager and its visual studio support package to write my custom code. Is it a decent assumption?
2. After I am done with my changes, how exactly I should package it into a module? (Using standard sitecore packaging or there is something more?)
3. What content goes into the package? (Only the items that I changed or the entire content base?)
4. How do I upload the module and ask someone to review it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can setup your local Sitecore instance how ever you want. You
   can use Sitecore Instance Manager if you want as that provides an
   easy way to get a Sitecore instance up and running.
2. Once you have completed your module, you want to use the built in
   Sitecore Package Designer. You'll add any Sitecore items that the
   module needs (Layouts, renderings/sublayouts, custom buttons, etc.)
   and any files that need to live on the file system (configuration
   files, DLLs, rendering views, etc.)
3. Only items that are specific to your module should be included.
4. You'll want to go to the [Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Contribute.aspx), sign in then
   click the "Contribute Now" button. Fill out the form(s) and you
   should have your module available on the marketplace.

While developing your module it would also be good to look over the [Sitecore module implementation practices](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/831724) Knowledge base article for best practice.

Comment: @same time, your file system changes should go into /website/sitecore modules/[Module Name] excluding dlls files & config files. This comes handy while debugging your module changes + Easy to uninstall the module if these standards are followed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for lot of good pointers. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

About 2) Packaging the module.
You can automate with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.
When Unicorn 4 is released there is a intresting new way to generate you module package, because generating packages from Unicorn with Powershell is a new feature.

See:
[Unicorn 4 Preview Part 2.5: Generating Unicorn Packages with SPE](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/02/Unicorn-4-Preview-Part-2-5-Generating-Packages-with-SPE/)

Now not yet been released but good to keep an eye on.